# "Not only from [...] but also from [...]"

Tags: prepositions, construction

> Students can acquire knowledge not only from educational institutions, but also **from** many other ways.

In the above sentence, is *from* following "but also" needed, or can it be removed as in the following sentence?

> Students can acquire knowledge from not only educational institutions, but also many other ways.

Comment: **<comments removed>** Please try to avoid answering these questions in comments. If you have an answer, please use the 'answer' function. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertCartaino: Now I'm curious what those comments were all about. I often post partial answers in comments, when I don't have time to write a full answer. Anything wrong with that? And why delete it, as long as it helps the OP?

Comment: @RobertCartaino Please do not delete such comments without consulting our local moderators, who are familiar with our folkways. It is customary here to post partial answers, or brief answers not closely argued, both to narrow the focus of questions to those matters which are most likely to be of interest to future readers and as a courtesy to OP, assuring that an answer of some value is provided quickly, even if the question must be closed. Thank you for your attention to the site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The rule when you use the *not only ... but also ...* construction is that the two strings where the ellipsis dots fall must be strictly parallel: what comes ***before*** *not only* must combine with what comes ***after*** *but also* to form an acceptable sentence:

> **Students can acquire knowledge from <sub>not only educational institutions, but also</sub> many other ways.

So If *from many other ways* were idiomatic, your alternative would be acceptable. However, we don't do things ***from*** ways but ***in*** ways. Accordingly, to maintain parallelism, the prepositions must be moved inside the construction:

> Students can acquire knowledge not only **from** educational institutions but also **in** many other ways.